# Advice - href links from a external file

Tags: php, xml, cordova

I was wondering if you could offer some advice.  I want to create a simple phonegap project (HTML) that would allow me to have href links created using values from a separate file.  I would like the app to run and get all of the href values from a single file on the memory card.

I was thinking this file would be made up of tags, one indicating the tags name (so you can direct in html which link is which), its value (e.g. google.com).

I was thinking this might be possible with xml or php?

As you can tell I am a beginner at this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Xml seems like a good choice.

Create your XML file with all your url in it.

Then use the [PhoneGap File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File) to open and read the XML file.

Then I suggest [you learn about XML parsing in Javascript](http://www.google.com/search?q=XML%20parsing%20javadcript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=fr&sa=X&ei=kCVeT_jqFoay0QXmpsTXDQ&ved=0CB4QvwUoAQ&q=XML%20parsing%20javascript&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4158a3fa7343a600&biw=1280&bih=719)

If you have any problem, let us know.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm having trouble finding the information I need. e.g. examples etc  What I want to be able to do is have a simple html website point its href links to a sting in xml.  So it would look something like <a href=@yahoo></a> and in  the xml document it would be <google>http://www.google.com</google><yahoo>http://www.yahoo.com</yahoo>